# How to Create A Timer in C++ Can't figure out CALLBACK's Timer ID value

Tags: c++, timer

Now using a **TimerProc**.

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(

    HWND hwnd,  // handle of window for timer messages 
    UINT uMsg,  // WM_TIMER message
    UINT idEvent,   // timer identifier
    DWORD dwTime    // current system time
   );
```

It is called by the system to process an associated Timer's WM_TIMER message. Let's see some code.

```
#define IDT_TIMER1 1001
...

/* The Timer Procedure */
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd,   
                    UINT uMsg,  
                    UINT idEvent,   
                    DWORD dwTime)
   {
          MessageBox(NULL, "One second is passed, the timer procedure is called, killing the timer", "Timer Procedure", MB_OK);

          KillTimer(hwnd, idEvent);
   }

...

/* Creating the timer */
SetTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1, 1000, (TIMERPROC)TimerProc);

...
```

How do I obtain `IDT_TIMER1` in the `TimerProc`? the idEvent doesn't match this value and uMsg is always 0x110 (WM_TIMER), is it encoded somehow because the idEvent is like `0x739B` while `IDT_TIMER1` is `1001` `(0x3E9)`

Comment: Your code is simply incorrect. The definition of TimerProc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ms644907) is different than yours.

Comment: Fixed it and it works .. no idea what you are talking about its correct.

Comment: If you read documentation link, you will know what I am talking about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out from documentation.

```
idEvent - Specifies a nonzero timer identifier. If the `hWnd` parameter is NULL, this parameter is ignored.
```

so it's getting ignored.

Fixed it like this

```
#define IDT_TIMER_1 1001
UINT_PTR Timer1IdEvent;

Timer1IdEvent = SetTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1, 1000, (TIMERPROC)TimerProc);
...

VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd,   
                    UINT uMsg,  
                    UINT idEvent,   
                    DWORD dwTime)
   {

          if( Timer1IdEvent == idEvent) {
              MessageBox(NULL, "One second is passed, the timer procedure is called, killing the timer", "Timer Procedure", MB_OK);

              KillTimer(hwnd, idEvent);
          }
   }
```